# Can't make dlib app with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, dlib

I use **python3.6.0, dlib** and some other packages.
Then I try to make .app from my .py, pyinstaller does great job, but when I try to open it, there is Error Message saying:

```
"ImportError: dlopen(/Users/*/Desktop/Searcher/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/dlib.so, 2):                   
**Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpng16.16.dylib**
Referenced from: 
/Users/*/Desktop/Searcher/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/dlib.so      
**Reason: Incompatible library version: dlib.so requires version 51.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 38.0.0**"
```

What should I do to make my program work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps here should help:

https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/357